# Apache CXF WSDL2Java -exsh returns not in the enumeration value list

Tags: cxf

I'm using CXF 2.5.2 with Maven, it works fine without specifying -exsh. But when I do it says

-exsh file:/C:/wsdl/XXXX.wsdl not in the enumeration value list!

I have no idea of whats the meaning of it. The option is supported and mentioned on the Usage line after that. I really need to get it working as a bunch of methods have soap:header elements in the WSDL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I incorrectly assumed that adding -exsh as extraarg was enough to specify I want it to be true, it work this way:

```
 <extraargs>
           <extraarg>-exsh</extraarg>
           <extraarg>true</extraarg>
 </extraargs>
```